# How to override scala def close(): Future[Unit] in java

Tags: java, scala

title says it all.  I can't seem to get it to compile at all from java and I need to override the function

```
def close(): Future[Unit]
```

but I need to do so in java.

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: from Java, you need to use `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit` for Scala classes that have `Unit`.

Given a Scala class like

```
abstract class ScalaFoo {
  def close(): Future[Unit]
}
```

your Java class must extend it like so:

```
class JavaFoo extends ScalaFoo {
    @Override
    public Future<BoxedUnit> close() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The reason for this indirection is a quirk of [Scala's Type Hierarchy](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128):  `Unit` is a `scala.AnyVal` (as opposed to a `scala.AnyRef`/`java.lang.Object`) and thus has no convenient Java equivalent.